# Read-only email client for archived emails

Tags: email, email-client, thunderbird

I have emails exported from accounts I no longer have access to.

I'd like to be able to import and search them in "archival mode", with the following features.

- No accidental deletion
- Good search and browsing UI for multiple email accounts
- Offline mode

I'm currently considering importing the emails to thunderbird, disabling sync, and just try to be careful not to delete. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but you can achieve read-only by dening yourself file-system permisions to write on the email client's database file.